# github organizational private repository access to everyone

Tags: github

I'd like an organizational private (as in not shared with the internets) repository to be accessible to all organization members, regardless of teams. Preferably for both read and write, but only read is also acceptable.

I might be missing something, but without creating (and therefor maintaining) an 'everyone' team I can't think of a way to configure that.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like something you might want to bring to the attention of the GitHub support. If you already checked and it’s not possible, then there is very little we can do here.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by:

1. Create a private repository in the organization
2. On the organization settings define the default access level to:

- Read (every member of the organization has read access)
- or Write (every member of the organization has read/write access)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I would like to do that for a single repository, not all repositories in an organization (and yes, it's a paid one).

Comment: If so the default access level defined in member privileges won't work because this applies to ALL repositories. This is only possible to achieve with teams if some repositories can be seen/written by everyone but others not. Default access level is great for when the policy applies to all repositories.